# How to calculate the projective transformation matrix given two planes?

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, affine-geometry, computer-vision

When projecting an image from one plane $\left\{ A \right\}$ to another plane $\left\{ B \right\}$, we have
$X' = \mathbf{H} \cdot X$
Namely,
$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\ y'\\ 1\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{11} & h_{12} & h_{13}\\
h_{21} & h_{22} & h_{23}\\
h_{31} & h_{32} & h_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$
Now, if we know the equation/relationship between the two planes,
e.g.
$^B_A\mathbf{T} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{n} & \mathbf{o} & \mathbf{a} & \mathbf{p} \\ 
0 &0 &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$,
where, $\mathbf{p}$ is the translate vector between from {A} origin to {B} origin. How to calculate the transformation matrix $\mathbf{H}$?
Especially, for the parameters $h_{31}$ and $h_{32}$.
In affine transformation $h_{31} = 0, h_{32} = 0$.
However, in projective transformation $h_{31} = ~?,~ h_{32} = ~?$.

Comment: His is not a unique mapping, so more information is needed. Where are the origins of each plane (where is [0,0]) located, and which way is each of _x_-axis and _y_-axis goes?

Comment: I update the question again. There is a translate vector between the two origins.

Answer (score 0):

With the transformation equation you can calculate four related $(x_i,y_i) \sim (u_i,v_i)$ points in both planes and with this it's easy to calculate using

$$Ah=0$$

Where

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
-x_1 & -y_1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_1u_1 & y_1u_1 & u_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -x_1 & -y_1 & -1 & x_1v_1 & y_1v_1 & v_1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
-x_4 & -y_4 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & x_4u_4 & y_4u_4 & u_4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -x_4 & -y_4 & -1 & x_4v_4 & y_4v_4 & v_4 
\end{matrix}\right)$$

and

$$h =\left(\begin{matrix} h_{11} & h_{12} & h_{13} & h_{21} & h_{22} & h_{23} & h_{31} & h_{32} \end{matrix}\right) $$

Comment: Hi, Cofinite, Thank you for your answer. I only know the relationship of the two plane, I don’t know the point’s coordinate. Can I get the **H** according to the two planes relationship?